# Android app terminates after certain time when minimized

Tags: java, android

I have this app which parses SMS and then converts them into Audio. My app users usually minimize the app and runs it all the time. But my app is getting terminated after sometime. How can i make sure my app will run till a user "terminates" it. Since the core functionality of the app is to convert SMS to audio, i need it running all the time.How can i do this ?

My current **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtGateway, txtTime, txtAmount;
    Speakerbox speakerbox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //textView = findViewById(R.id.txt_message);
        speakerbox = new Speakerbox(getApplication());
        txtAmount = findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
        txtGateway = findViewById(R.id.tv_gateway);
        txtTime = findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        requestSmsPermission();

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("otp"));
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("otp"));
        super.onPause();
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("otp")) {
                final String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                String gateway = intent.getStringExtra("gateway");
                String time = intent.getStringExtra("time");
                String amount = intent.getStringExtra("amount");
                speakerbox.play(message);
                txtGateway.setText(gateway);
                txtTime.setText(time);
                txtAmount.setText(amount);


                // message is the fetching OTP
            }
        }
    };




    /**
     * Requesting multiple permissions (storage and location) at once
     * This uses multiple permission model from dexter
     * On permanent denial opens settings dialog
     */
    private void requestSmsPermission() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(
                        Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions are granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                            showSettingsDialog();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).
                withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DexterError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .onSameThread()
                .check();
    }

    /**
     * Showing Alert Dialog with Settings option
     * Navigates user to app settings
     * NOTE: Keep proper title and message depending on your app
     */
    private void showSettingsDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Need Permissions");
        builder.setMessage("This app needs permission to use this feature. You can grant them in app settings.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("GOTO SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                openSettings();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }

    // navigating user to app settings
    private void openSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the stacktrace of crash

Comment: It doesnt crash. OS silently kills the app

Comment: Then its a memory issue. You need to use a service as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Try to use a foreground service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a foreground service to ensure that your app is not killed by Android. On newer version of Android, app's background process gets killed after sometime. Having a foreground service will ensure that your app stays active. Keep the service on background thread and not on the main thread.

Read more at:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services
and
https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/

Comment: So do we need to initiate the foreground service from my MainActivity ?

Comment: You can initiate it from any activity or also using broadcast.

Comment: Right now i have a BroadcastReceiver registered on my MainActivity. Basically waits for SMS from certain Number and displays it in my main activity. I would like the message to displayed in a foreground activity without OS killing it. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbpD5RZtbCc
Is this the correct way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

Activities are used for user facing parts of your application. Use service instead. Most likely, your application is getting terminated by os due to low memory situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use service for the core functionality if you want to run all the time in background.If user is not using your app actively yet app is taking RAM memory then OS will terminate the app to avoid out of memory.

Comment: But i read in the new android OS, even services will be terminated after sometime. Is there any solution ? Also how can i convert my current Activity into a service ? Any reference would be appreciated